# Adding Hours for Data and time in Python

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

i want to add 5:30 for but am getting

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from openerp.tools import float_is_zero, float_compare, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
AppointmentDateTime = etree.SubElement(ServiceHeader, 'AppointmentDateTime')
            if self.app_date:
                app_date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(AppointmentDateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
                print ">>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<", app_date
                AppointmentDateTime.text = app_date
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: `datetime.strptime(..)` not `datetime.datetime.strptime(..)`

Comment: Thank you, yea tried. this giving "TypeError: must be string, not lxml.etree._Element"

Comment: `datetime.strptime(..)` expects a string

Comment: Thank yo, it works